# Lax representation of the harmonic oscillator

Tags: mathematical-physics, harmonic-oscillator, representation-theory, integrable-systems

Peter Lax showed that the differential operators $$L=-6\partial_x^2-u,\quad B=-4\partial_x^3-u\partial_x-(1/2)u_x$$ fulfilling the Lax equation $$\dot{L}+[L,B]=0$$ is equivalent to the KdV equation $$u_t+uu_x+u_{xxx}=0.$$

For the harmonic oscillator one knows a Lax representation given by two two-by-two matrices.

**But:** Are there differential operators $L$ and $B$ which are equivalent to the harmonic oscillator equation $$\ddot{q}+\omega q=0$$ and fulfilling the Lax equation? If yes: How can one derive the form of these operators?

Comment: Do you mean that Lax proved $(\dot{L}+[L,B])u=0 \Leftrightarrow u_t+u u_x + u_{xxx}=0$? (in particular, the $x$ is taken to be independent from time? i.e. $\partial_t (\partial^2_x)=\partial^2_x\partial_t$ or not?) However this is a PDE while the harmonic oscillator equation is an ODE.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Besides the fact that the harmonic oscillator is an ODE, is there no way to write down such matrices? Yes x is independent of time, so everything commutes.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if I understand completely, because $L=\partial_t$ and $B=\omega t$ (where $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ does not depend on time) seem to do what you are asking...I will use the symbol $\partial$ here even if there is only $t$ as a variable, so it is not so meaningful (but shorter to write): $\partial_t L q=\partial_t^2 q$; $LBq=\omega q+\omega t\partial_t q$, $BLq=\omega t\partial_t q$, i.e. $[L,B]q=\omega q$.

Answer (score 4):

Well, consider a Lax pair for the Harmonic Oscillator;
\begin{equation}
L =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  p & \omega q \\
  \omega q & -p \\
 \end{pmatrix}, \quad M=\frac{\omega}{2} 
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
  1& 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Since the Hamiltonian is
$$H(q, p)=\frac{1}{2}(p^{2}+\omega^{2}q^{2})$$
It is eay to check that the Lax equation $\dot{L}=[M, L ]$ is equivalent to the Hamiltonian system
\begin{equation}
\dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=p, \quad  \dot{p}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}=-\omega^{2}q
\end{equation}
It is a trivial exercise to show that
\begin{equation}
\ddot{q}+\omega^{2}q=0
\end{equation}